# Parsing xml string and get rid of root element error

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, umbraco

I have this string structured as XML:

```
<damp fullmedia="">
  <mediaitem>
    <img id="1119" version="29a5623f-d41c-4418-97b7-3cea8579ffd8" parentid="1052" level="2" writerid="0" nodetype="1032" template="0" sortorder="2" createdate="2016-11-30T10:09:40" updatedate="2016-11-30T10:09:40" nodename="2016-11-25_1251411957-277" urlname="2016-11-25_1251411957-277" writername="admin" nodetypealias="Image" path="-1,1052,1119">
      <umbracofile>/media/1013/2016-11-25_1251411957-277.jpg</umbracofile>
      <umbracowidth>2598</umbracowidth>
      <umbracoheight>1732</umbracoheight>
      <umbracobytes>350613</umbracobytes>
      <umbracoextension>jpg</umbracoextension>    
    </img>
  </mediaitem>
</damp>
```

I want to extract the value of property "umbracofile", so I did this:

```
var stringAsXml = "<damp fullmedia="">....";
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
var imageUrl = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//mediaItem/img/umbracoFile").InnerText;
```

The code works fine but I have the error "Root element is missing". As I just want to parse and extract a node value, how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: `The code works fine but I have the error` I'd argue that these statements are actually contradictory.  Error might be related to fact that you are looking for node `Image` when the node is actually `img`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the node find /img/ not /Image/

Comment: Oh, your `img` tag is also never closed.  I don't know if that's a typo

Comment: It was a typo, I fixed it, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code works fine but I have the error "Root element is missing".

Then the code doesn't work that fine I guess? This should work:

```
var stringAsXml = "<damp fullmedia=\"\"><mediaitem><img id=\"1119\" version=\"29a5623f-d41c-4418-97b7-3cea8579ffd8\" parentid=\"1052\" level=\"2\" writerid=\"0\" nodetype=\"1032\" template=\"0\" sortorder=\"2\" createdate=\"2016-11-30T10:09:40\" updatedate=\"2016-11-30T10:09:40\" nodename=\"2016-11-25_1251411957-277\" urlname=\"2016-11-25_1251411957-277\" writername=\"admin\" nodetypealias=\"Image\" path=\"-1,1052,1119\"><umbracofile>/media/1013/2016-11-25_1251411957-277.jpg</umbracofile><umbracowidth>2598</umbracowidth><umbracoheight>1732</umbracoheight><umbracobytes>350613</umbracobytes><umbracoextension>jpg</umbracoextension></img></mediaitem></damp>";
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(stringAsXml);
var imageUrl = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("damp/mediaitem/img/umbracofile").InnerText;
```

And this as well (if you have several `<umbracofile>` nodes and want to select the first one):

```
var imageUrl = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//umbracofile").InnerText;
```